# Get output of getchar without defining it as a variable

Tags: vim

Is there a way to reference the character that was consumed by `getchar()` ? For example:

```
inoremap [   []<Left><C-r>=(nr2char(getchar()) == ']'?'':'X')<CR>
```

How do replace `'X'` with the character retrieved from `getchar()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning the output of a function to some kind of variable (variable, key in a dictionary, etc.) is the only way to make it reusable, in vimscript as well as in any other common scripting language.

--- EDIT ---

To answer your comment, proper functions are always preferable to one-liners because they are easier to read, easier to understand, and easier to maintain:

```
function! My_func(nr)
    let my_char = nr2char(a:nr)
    return my_char == ']' ? '' : my_char
endfunction
inoremap [ []<Left><C-r>=My_func(getchar())<CR><CR>
```

Comment: could you please show how that would be done in the mapping then? For some reason I wasn't able to define any cariable in `C-r=`, so it seems I'd need to write a function it calls?